# Separating words with Regex (Not in specific order)

Tags: regex

Extracting from text For example; the following sentence contains the initial capital letters. How can I separate them?

**Text:**

> A. lorem ipsum dolor sit B . 41dipiscing elit sedC. lorem ipsum dolor
>   sit amet D. 35 Consectetur adipiscing E .Sed do eiusmod tempor

**Goal:**

```
A. lorem ipsum dolor sit 
B . 41dipiscing elit sed 
C. lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
D. 35 Consectetur adipiscing 
E .Sed do eiusmod tempor
```

**What have I done?**

```
^(([a-zA-Z]{1}|[0-9]+)\s*[.,]{1})(.*)$
```

**Result:**

https://regex101.com/r/4HB0oD/1

But my Regex code doesn't detect it without first sentence. What is the reason of this?

Comment: Note that the quantifier `{1}` is inherently redundant. If you want to match something once, simply don't add a quantifier.

Comment: What is the tool or language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern should do what you're looking for:

`[A-Z\d] ?\..+?(?=$|[A-Z\d] ?\.)`

https://regex101.com/r/i92QR1/1

Comment: What happens if any digit instead of letter?

Comment: @Emre You mean you need the pattern to also match digits in place of where "A." "B." "C." etc. are located?

Comment: Yes, number instead of letters

Comment: That can be done simply by adding `\d` to the character sets that match the capital letters. I've updated the pattern to show this.

Comment: I wonder why doesn't detect it [Regex with full text](https://regex101.com/r/i92QR1/2)

Comment: Looks like it's working to me. Look at the "Match Information" box on the right side.

Comment: Thank you for answer. By the way; I opened a new question. I'd appreciate it if you wanted to check i. [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59329404/separate-group-plain-text-with-regex-and-php)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe,

```
(?=[A-Z]\s*\.)
```

might work OK.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BR7FHE/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

string = '''
A. lorem ipsum dolor sit B . 41dipiscing elit sedC. lorem ipsum dolor sit amet D. 35 Consectetur adipiscing E .Sed do eiusmod tempor
'''

print(re.sub(r'(?=[A-Z]\s*\.)', '\n', string))
```

#### Output

```
A. lorem ipsum dolor sit 
B . 41dipiscing elit sed
C. lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
D. 35 Consectetur adipiscing 
E .Sed do eiusmod tempor
```

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/BR7FHE/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/BR7FHE/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]