# Separate/Group plain text with Regex and PHP

Tags: php, r, arrays, json, regex

I can separate data from the plain text below with Regex.

Plain text:

> 190.A 42-year-old male patient has been delivered to a hospital in a grave condition with dyspnea, cough with expectoration of purulent
> sputum, fever up to 39,5 oC.The ?rst symptoms appeared 3 weeks ago.
> Two weeks ago, a local therapist diagnosed him wi- th acute
> right-sided pneumonia. Over the last 3 days, the patient’s condition
> deteriorated: there was a progress of dyspnea, weakness, lack of
> appetite. Chest radiography con?rms a rounded shadow in the lower lobe
> of the right lung with a horizontal?uid level, the right si- nus is
> not clearly visualized. What is the most likely diagnosis? A.Abscess
> of the right lung B.Acute pleuropneumonia C.Right pulmonary empyema
> D.Atelectasis of the right lung E.Pleural effusion 191.An 11-year-old
> boy complains of general weakness, fever up to 38,2 oC, pain and
> swelli- ng of the knee joints, feeling of irregular heartbeat. 3 weeks
> ago, the child had quinsy. Knee joints are swollen, the overlying skin
> and skin of the knee region is reddened, local temperature is
> increased, movements are li- mited. Heart sounds are muf?ed,
> extrasystole is present, auscultation reveals apical systolic murmur
> that is not conducted to the left ingui- nal region. ESR is 38 mm/h.
> CRP is 2+, anti- streptolysin O titre - 40 0. What is the most likely
> diagnosis? A.Acute rheumatic fever B.Vegetative dysfunction
> C.Non-rheumatic carditis D.Juvenile rheumatoid arthritis E.Reactive
> arthritis 192.A 28-year-old male patient complains of sour
> regurgitation, cough and heartburn that occurs every day after having
> meals, when bending forward or lying down. These problems have been
> observed for 4 years. Objective status and laboratory values are
> normal. FEGDS revealed endoesophagitis. What is the leading factor in
> the development of this disease? A.Failure of the lower esophageal
> sphincter B.Hypersecretion of hydrochloric acid C.Duodeno-gastric
> re?ux D.Hypergastrinemia E.Helicobacter pylori infection 193.On
> admission a 35-year-old female reports acute abdominal pain, fever up
> to 38,8 oC, mucopurulent discharges. The pati- ent is nulliparous, has
> a history of 2 arti?cial abortions. The patient is unmarried, has
> sexual Krok 2 Medicine 20 14 24 contacts. Gynecological examination
> reveals no uterus changes. Appendages are enlarged, bilaterally
> painful. There is profuse purulent vaginal discharge. What study is
> required to con?rm the diagnosis? A.Bacteriologic and bacteriascopic
> studies B.Hysteroscopy C.Curettage of uterine cavity D.Vaginoscopy
> E.Laparoscopy

**What did I do for this?**

For the question section:

```
/(\d+)\.\s*([A-Z].*?)\s+([A-Z]\..*?)(?=\d+\.\s*[A-Z]|$)/s
```

For the options of question section:

```
/\s+(?=[A-Z0-9][,.:])
```

PHP:

```
$soruAlimPattern = [
            'q&a' => '/(\d+)\.\s*([A-Z].*?)\s+([A-Z]\..*?)(?=\d+\.\s*[A-Z]|$)/s',
            'answers' => '/\s+(?=[A-Z0-9][,.:])/'
        ];
        $res = [];
        if (preg_match_all($soruAlimPattern['q&a'], $temizSoruCikisi, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER) > 0) {
            foreach ($out AS $k => $v) {
                // remove the full match ($0)
                $res[$k] = array_slice($v, 1, 3);
                // split the answers
                $res[$k][2] = preg_split($soruAlimPattern['answers'], $res[$k][2]);
            }
        }
        $sorularJsonKodlaniyor = json_encode($res);
       [...]
```

I can distinguish between question and question options, but is it possible to use a **single Regex code** instead of 2 different Regex?
I don't know how quality the PHP code is but it works.

```
My problem:

 1. Sometimes there are unidentifiable letters in the question and these
    undefined characters are indicated with a question mark. For
    example: `fever up to 39,5 oC.The ?rst symptoms` or `..39,5 oC.The ?rst symptoms..`

2. Due to the numerical values in the question, the Regex code divides the question in half. For example: `... anti- streptolysin O titre - 40 0. What is the most likely diagnosis? ` In fact, the question divides the question because of the number "zero".
```

Expected JSON Format:

```
[
  {
    "question": "190.A 42-year-old male patient has been delivered to a hospital in a grave condition with dyspnea, cough with expectoration of purulent sputum, fever up to 39,5 oC.The ?rst symptoms appeared 3 weeks ago. Two weeks ago, a local therapist diagnosed him wi- th acute right-sided pneumonia. Over the last 3 days, the patient’s condition deteriorated: there was a progress of dyspnea, weakness, lack of appetite. Chest radiography con?rms a rounded shadow in the lower lobe of the right lung with a horizontal?uid level, the right si- nus is not clearly visualized. What is the most likely diagnosis? ",
    "answers": [
      "A.Abscess of the right lung ",
      "B.Acute pleuropneumonia ",
      "C.Right pulmonary empyema ",
      "D.Atelectasis of the right lung ",
      "E.Pleural effusion 1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "question": "191.An 11-year-old boy complains of general weakness, fever up to 38,2 oC, pain and swelli- ng of the knee joints, feeling of irregular heartbeat. 3 weeks ago, the child had quinsy. Knee joints are swollen, the overlying skin and skin of the knee region is reddened, local temperature is increased, movements are li- mited. Heart sounds are muf?ed, extrasystole is present, auscultation reveals apical systolic murmur that is not conducted to the left ingui- nal region. ESR is 38 mm/h. CRP is 2+, anti- streptolysin O titre - 40 0. What is the most likely diagnosis? ",
    "answers": [
      "A.Acute rheumatic fever ",
      "B.Vegetative dysfunction ",
      "C.Non-rheumatic carditis ",
      "D.Juvenile rheumatoid arthritis ",
      "E.Reactive arthritis 1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "question": "192.A 28-year-old male patient complains of sour regurgitation, cough and heartburn that occurs every day after having meals, when bending forward or lying down. These problems have been observed for 4 years. Objective status and laboratory values are normal. FEGDS revealed endoesophagitis. What is the leading factor in the development of this disease? ",
    "answers": [
      "A.Failure of the lower esophageal sphincter ",
      "B.Hypersecretion of hydrochloric acid ",
      "C.Duodeno-gastric re?ux ",
      "D.Hypergastrinemia ",
      "E.Helicobacter pylori infection 1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "question": "193.On admission a 35-year-old female reports acute abdominal pain, fever up to 38,8 oC, mucopurulent discharges. The pati- ent is nulliparous, has a history of 2 arti?cial abortions. The patient is unmarried, has sexual Krok 2 Medicine 20 14 24 contacts. Gynecological examination reveals no uterus changes. Appendages are enlarged, bilaterally painful. There is profuse purulent vaginal discharge. What study is required to con?rm the diagnosis? ",
    "answers": [
      "A.Bacteriologic and bacteriascopic studies ",
      "B.Hysteroscopy ",
      "C.Curettage of uterine cavity ",
      "D.Vaginoscopy ",
      "E.Laparoscopy 1"
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I overcome these problems?

Comment: Thank you for giving us tons of information, it's very useful! Still one question remains though, what exactly is your expected output?

Comment: Thank you Emre, can you post the JSON-formatted data you're expected in your question (it's typical here in case a link ever goes down - that way it's accessible to future users too!). We can definitely help you with this though. It's nice to see a new user putting effort into asking their question :)

Comment: I updated my question.but I don't think anyone can help :) The question is not even on the home page.. @ctwheels

Comment: That's super helpful, just want to confirm cause the output has `90` instead off `190` - I assume it's a typo?

Comment: @ctwheels Yes, typo, number 1 is missing. I added

Comment: How is it related to “R”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might do is use [preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to get all the strings with the right characters at the start like `190.A` or `A.`

```
\b(?=(?:\d+|[A-Z])\.[A-Z])
```

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `(?:\d+|[A-Z])` Match either 1+ digits or a single char A-Z
  - `\.[A-Z]` Match `.` and a single char A-Z
- `)` Close positive lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iKX9Ru/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/RYbea)

If you have all those entries in an array, you could for example use [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to the get array structure that you need for the json output.

```
$pattern = "/\b(?=(?:\d+|[A-Z])\.[A-Z])/";
$result = preg_split($pattern, $data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$result = array_reduce($result, function($carry, $item){

    // If the string starts with a digit
    if (ctype_digit(substr($item, 0, 1))) {

        // Create the  questions key
        $carry[] = ["question" => $item];
        return $carry;
    }

    // Get reference to the last added array in $carry
    end($carry);
    $last = &$carry[key($carry)];

    // Create the answers key
    array_key_exists("answers", $last) ? $last["answers"][] = $item : $last["answers"] = [$item];
    return $carry;
}, []);

print_r(json_encode($result))
```

Output

```
[
    {
        "question": "190.A 42-year-old male patient has been delivered to a hospital in a grave condition with dyspnea, cough with expectoration of purulent sputum, fever up to 39,5 oC.The ?rst symptoms appeared 3 weeks ago. Two weeks ago, a local therapist diagnosed him wi- th acute right-sided pneumonia. Over the last 3 days, the patient\u2019s condition deteriorated: there was a progress of dyspnea, weakness, lack of appetite. Chest radiography con?rms a rounded shadow in the lower lobe of the right lung with a horizontal?uid level, the right si- nus is not clearly visualized. What is the most likely diagnosis? ",
        "answers": [
            "A.Abscess of the right lung ",
            "B.Acute pleuropneumonia ",
            "C.Right pulmonary empyema ",
            "D.Atelectasis of the right lung ",
            "E.Pleural effusion "
        ]
    },
    {
        "question": "191.An 11-year-old boy complains of general weakness, fever up to 38,2 oC, pain and swelli- ng of the knee joints, feeling of irregular heartbeat. 3 weeks ago, the child had quinsy. Knee joints are swollen, the overlying skin and skin of the knee region is reddened, local temperature is increased, movements are li- mited. Heart sounds are muf?ed, extrasystole is present, auscultation reveals apical systolic murmur that is not conducted to the left ingui- nal region. ESR is 38 mm\/h. CRP is 2+, anti- streptolysin O titre - 40 0. What is the most likely diagnosis? ",
        "answers": [
            "A.Acute rheumatic fever ",
            "B.Vegetative dysfunction ",
            "C.Non-rheumatic carditis ",
            "D.Juvenile rheumatoid arthritis ",
            "E.Reactive arthritis "
        ]
    },
    {
        "question": "192.A 28-year-old male patient complains of sour regurgitation, cough and heartburn that occurs every day after having meals, when bending forward or lying down. These problems have been observed for 4 years. Objective status and laboratory values are normal. FEGDS revealed endoesophagitis. What is the leading factor in the development of this disease? ",
        "answers": [
            "A.Failure of the lower esophageal sphincter ",
            "B.Hypersecretion of hydrochloric acid ",
            "C.Duodeno-gastric re?ux ",
            "D.Hypergastrinemia ",
            "E.Helicobacter pylori infection "
        ]
    },
    {
        "question": "193.On admission a 35-year-old female reports acute abdominal pain, fever up to 38,8 oC, mucopurulent discharges. The pati- ent is nulliparous, has a history of 2 arti?cial abortions. The patient is unmarried, has sexual Krok 2 Medicine 20 14 24 contacts. Gynecological examination reveals no uterus changes. Appendages are enlarged, bilaterally painful. There is profuse purulent vaginal discharge. What study is required to con?rm the diagnosis? ",
        "answers": [
            "A.Bacteriologic and bacteriascopic studies ",
            "B.Hysteroscopy ",
            "C.Curettage of uterine cavity ",
            "D.Vaginoscopy ",
            "E.Laparoscopy"
        ]
    }
]
```